# PHP Photo Uploads - upload_tmp_dir permissions

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, photos

I'm using the following directory for php.ini photo uploads on apache - redhat/AWS

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 user2 user2 4096 Mar  4 08:10 datingPhotoUploads
```

Apache is running as the user 'apache'.

How can I give this folder permissions so the user 'apache' can write to it but otherwise its as secure as possible?

thankyou

Comment: I suppose you already did it but don't forget to find out whether *PHP* runs as "apache".

Comment: yes it runs as apache - eg: ps aux | grep apache
- this list apache as the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the upload_tmp_dir is /tmp. This /tmp directory as some special rights (`chmod 1777`), where the really special right is the `1`. This is the sticky bit. It means, for directories, files created in this directory can only be deleted by the file owner, even if any other `rwx` rights seems to apply on file.

So having uploaded files stored in a temporary folder with **1777** rights uploaded by apache users means only apache can delete theses files. A good starting point.

You could use this right on your **datingPhotoUploads** directory. But you could also try to manage it with group ownership of the directory (`chmod user2:apache; chmod 2770 datingPhotoUploads;`). Here the 770 part of chmod means read and write and delete for user and group owner of the chmod part. The `2` means every file created on this directory will have the same ownership as the directory, so `user2:apache`.

The main problems of upload_tmp_dir are:

- **Is this apache writeable directory reachable by the apache user?** If you are not using `/tmp` but `/some/where/datingPhotoUpload`, apache must be able to read directories content for `/some` and `/some/where`. So the x right part must be set for others (or for group if apache is the group owner) for all theses preceding paths.
- **Is this paths available for all my php application or only the running one?** This is the main problem with `/tmp`, this directory is available for all PHP application running on your host. Altering upload_tmp_dir on a per-application basis can restrict access to other applications, especially if you set **open_basedir** restrictions on all php applications and that only the current application allows `/some/where/datingPhotoUpload` in the `open_basedir` setting.
- **Is this directory big enough in size?** Be carefull with big uploads or mass-uploads. What will happen when this directory will be filled by a malicious user?
- **Am I sure there is no way to execute any code in this directory?** Uploading images containing php code in exim data is an example of code inclusion attacks, are you sure this directory is outside the web server Directory root? are you sure any special path targeting this directory would not allow php execution (remove php handlers on this Directory maybe)?

Answer (score 2):

To upload images (create files) folder should have `-wx` permissions.
Writing only reqires `--x` (same as reading and executing).

To check what user php is running as use: `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`.